# Should I create a new tag 'HaxeFlixel'?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've been weighing the idea of creating a new tag but I'm unsure if the tag I want to add meets the requirements. The tag I'm considering adding is `HaxeFlixel`.

### Some background

For those who don't know, [HaxeFlixel](http://www.haxeflixel.com/) is a 2d game framework written in the Haxe language. It is one of many frameworks that is build on top of OpenFL, but I believe it distinguishes itself in its popularity. HaxeFlixel is a port of the Flash Actionscript library [Flixel](http://flixel.org/).

### Why a new tag?

The privileges page has this to say:

> **When should I create new tags?**
>
> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always
>   favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a
>   strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else
>   has asked about before on this site.

There is already a `haxe` tag and a `flixel` tag. However, these tages feel insufficient to me because HaxeFlixel is not a simple 1-to-1 port -- the API has changed, features have been added and removed, and of course being written in Haxe means it evokes many challenges that are not relevant to a Flash library (such as targeting mobile platforms, file system access, etc).

Haxeflixel already has at least [some popularity](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=haxeflixel) on this site, and it is currently being tagged as a combination of `haxe` and `flixel`. In my mind this makes it difficult to follow content that is truly about HaxeFlixel.

So, does the community feel that this would be a valuable tag to add?

Comment: Just add it. There is no need to create this post to ask about it. If we like it, it will stay...

Comment: Perhaps my question should be re-worded as "Should I just create new tags and not worry about the consequences?" That's really the heart of what I was asking.

Comment: I do not see why not... That is why the "create tag" option exists...

Comment: @qwertynl I asked the question because it's unclear to me what the desired behavior is. If the community is fine with "just let the mods deal with it" then so be it, but that seems like an irresponsible default.

Comment: Tags have nothing to do with mods. tags are moderated the same way as questions -- by the "community". That is how 99.99999% of all of the tags got created! "By great viewers like you!"

Answer (score 2):

That is why the "create tag" option exists...

If the community does not like it, the community will let you know.

Comment: The answer of "try it and let the community agree or disagree" doesn't really answer the question - ***should*** this tag exist?

Comment: @slugster The whole reason for why "create tag" exists is for people to **create** tags :-)